# Objective C Why do I need to Type Cast in this situation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, appdelegate

I have a storyboard with the rootViewController class set to CoursesTableViewController.

Why in the appDelegate do I need to use a typecast as in this example...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    CoursesTableViewController *cvtc 
       = (CoursesTableViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

why can't I just do this...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    CoursesTableViewController *cvtc = self.window.rootViewController;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is called **downcasting**. You need to do that because polymorphism allows to assign a pointer to an object of a certain class, to a pointer to an object of a subclass of it's class, but not the viceversa (because it's not said that the pointer will actually point to an object that belongs to that subclass, while instead in the opposite case this is guaranteed).

This is the `UIWindow` property you're calling:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *rootViewController;
```

Like you see it's of type `UIViewController`,and `CoursesTableViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

**PS**: When I say it's needed I mean due to to avoid the compiler warning.

Comment: Now that you fixed it with the PS, I will remove my -1.

Answer (score 0):

`rootViewController` is a property of `UIWindow` of type `UIViewController`.

You need to cast it to your controller type, if you want to interface with properties and selectors specific to your type.

Comment: First, thanks to all for the quick response! My question is, because I set the class in the storyboard wouldn't the appDelegate know the controller type already?

Comment: Nope no way of changing a method or property definition dynamically.Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do that. It will just warn you about that, because is expecting one thing and he is seeing another. When you are casting is just way of letting the compiler know that it's ok what you are doing.

Its type:

[image]

Comment: First, thanks to all for the quick response! My question is, because I set the class in the storyboard wouldn't the appDelegate know the controller type already?

Comment: The rootViewController is expecting a `UIViewController`, not a `CoursesTableViewController`. That's why it behaves the way he does. Typecasting isn't the answer for everything, but in this case is what makes sense.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that. I mistakenly assumed the rootViewController automatically got it's type from the class selection in the storyboard. Thanks again!

Comment: You can check it's type by Jumping into its definition. Check my edit.